# Disabling Browse to Library in Media Upload Field

Tags: 7, media

I'm on Drupal 7.2 with the included Media Module. I'm also using WYSIWYG if that matters at all.

I'm seeing that when a user clicks the image upload field, they have a choice of either 'web' or 'library'.  The Library option shows all files that other users have uploaded to be included in other nodes. How do I disable that so that they don't see all the other files?

I don't use galleries- just upload/attach images to nodes that the users themselves create. Guests and Registered Users BOTH can see the nodes and image files- but I don't want them to have access to all the images that have been uploaded previously.

I think this has something to do with Private/Public, but I can't figure it out. Any input?

Comment: This is a current feature request in the media module issue queue and there appears to be a patch being tested. [Issue #992978: Add 'View media browser library' permissions](http://drupal.org/node/992978)

Answer (score 1):

On Drupal 8+ go to: `/admin/config/media/browser`

[image: Media browser options]

Set the "Enabled browser plugins" to only "upload" and save the page.

Now when people click on the button in the WYSIWYG to add something, they should only get the upload option and not see the library.

[image: Media popup]

Comment: The question said they were on Drupal 7.2

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a module, and this hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_media_browser_plugins_alter().
 */
function my_module_media_browser_plugins_alter(&$plugins) {
  // Hide the "Library" tab on the WYSIWYG media upload widget.
  unset($plugins['library']);
}
```